# Symfony2 Sort by DESC in controller

Tags: symfony, sql-order-by

I can't seem to figure how to sort by DESC in my controller code. I have a category entity that has a OneToMany with Post entity.

I am trying to sort the result from category->getPosts by DESC, it's automatically sorting by ASC.

I've tried a custom repo but I need posts by category, using the repo below gives me all posts not the ones specific to the category.

I know it's something simple I'm missing completely. How do I add in a orderBy with my current setup?

**This query worked for me:**

```
public function getBlogsByCategory($category)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('post')
        ->leftJoin('post.category','category')
        ->andWhere('category.title = :category')
        ->setParameter('category', $category)
        ->orderBy('post.createdAt', 'DESC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function showAction($category = null)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $category = $em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Category')
        ->findOneByTitle($category);

    if (!$category) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find blog posts');
    }

    $posts = $category->getPosts();


    return array(
        'posts'    => $posts,
        'category' => $category
    );
}
```

**Category entity**

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $title;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"title"}, unique=false)
 * @ORM\Column(length=255)
 */
private $slug;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Post", mappedBy="category")
 */
protected $posts;


public function __construct()
{
    $this->posts = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function __toString()
{
    return $this->getTitle() ? $this->getTitle() :  "";
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set title
 *
 * @param string $title
 * @return Category
 */
public function setTitle($title)
{
    $this->title = $title;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get title
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTitle()
{
    return $this->title;
}

/**
 * Set slug
 *
 * @param string $slug
 * @return Category
 */
public function setSlug($slug)
{
    $this->slug = $slug;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get slug
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getSlug()
{
    return $this->slug;
}

/**
 * Add posts
 *
 * @param Post $posts
 * @return Category
 */
public function addPost(Post $posts)
{
    $this->posts[] = $posts;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove posts
 *
 * @param Post $posts
 */
public function removePost(Post $posts)
{
    $this->posts->removeElement($posts);
}

/**
 * Get posts
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getPosts()
{
    return $this->posts;
}
```

**Post entity**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="posts")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $category;

/**
 * Set category
 *
 * @param \Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Category $category
 * @return Post
 */
public function setCategory(\Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Category $category = null)
{
    $this->category = $category;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get category
 *
 * @return \Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Category 
 */
public function getCategory()
{
    return $this->category;
}
```

**Post repo**

```
public function getPosts()
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->addOrderBy('p.createdAt', 'DESC');

    return $qb->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**

Since you are using custom repo already then you will have to modify your repo method to look like:

```
public function getOrderedPostsByCategory($categoryId)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->leftJoin('p.Category','c')
        ->addWhere('c.id = :categoryId')
        ->setParameter('c.categoryId', $categoryId)
        ->orderBy('p.createdAt', 'DESC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();

}
```

or second option would be to modify your `getPosts` method of entity and sort array in memory before doing `return $this->posts;`

Comment: Right I have tried this (see above), but I am looking for posts grouped by a specific category. The repo I'm using gives me all posts not the ones only for that category.

Comment: then you need to make your query more complex - do a join for category, group by category etc (just the way you would do that in pure sql)

Comment: Right, that is where I need help. Right now it works without the sorting. How do I join it to where it pull category blogs?

Comment: How would the second option work? I'm getting errors with the first option.

Comment: Getting the following with option 1: `[Semantical Error] line 0, col 69 near 'c WHERE c.id': Error: Class Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Category has no association named Category`

Comment: Second option would use plain php array sort http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php As for your error you need to have proper entity mapping - relation from post to category in this case

Comment: What's wrong with the mapping? Updated question with Post/Category entities. It's a Category: OneToMany / Post ManyToOne.

Comment: Try change Category to category (lowercase) in your query

Comment: changed p.Category to p.category. Same error only with a lowercase C in the last part of the error message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54901/discussion-between-tomasz-madeyski-and-dizzyd).

Answer (score 2):

```
public function getOrderedPostsByCategory($categoryId)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->leftJoin('p.category','c')
        ->addWhere('c.id = :categoryId')
        ->setParameter('categoryId', $categoryId)
        ->orderBy('p.createdAt', 'DESC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();

}
```

1) **p.category** put category in lowercase

2) and change p.categoryId into **categoryId** in setParameter

Comment: Just tried this, no errors but it's not pulling any posts. Getting the 404 error from my controller - 'unable to find blog posts'. It's not liking something in the query. and changed `addWhere` to `andWhere`

Comment: Figured it out am using category.title in my twig and not id. Works now. Sorry have to give it to Tomasz as he spent time to help through this. I upvoted your edited answer though, thanks fpanini.